# django 405 method not allowed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The error occurs when I request via post method.

views.py

```
class ConceptForkView(ConceptBaseView, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    print 'oclapi ConceptForkView111'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'oclapi ConceptForkView dispatch'
        return super(ConceptForkView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        print 'oclapi ConceptForkView post'
```

urls.py

`url(r'^forking/$', ConceptForkView.as_view(), name='concept-forking'),`

ConceptBaseView

```
class ConceptBaseView(ChildResourceMixin):

    lookup_field = 'concept'
    pk_field = 'mnemonic'
    model = Concept
    permission_classes = (CanViewParentDictionary,)
    child_list_attribute = 'concepts'
```

The command `print 'oclapi ConceptForkView111'` can run, but the method dispatch and post don't run. What is the reason?

I have searched many solutions, but they don't work to me. How can I solve  this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You don't provide clue about what `ChildResourceMixin` is

Answer (score 1):

Note that mixin is not a view. You probably have to inherit from View also. Mixins are usually classes that extend functionality and are not standalone. Class inheriting only from mixins probably won't work properly unless one of these mixins is not mixin in fact.

See: [rest framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview). There is `CreateAPIView` which inherits not only from `CreateModelMixin` but also from `GenericAPIView` (and you probably should inherit it too). As we can read about `GenericAPIView`:

> This class extends REST framework's APIView class, adding commonly required behavior for standard list and detail views.

So this "commonly required behavior" is important for your class to behave like view.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
def create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

method instead of

```
def post(self, request):
    ...
```

`CreateModelMixin` uses create method rather than post method